# Replace for loop with apply for faster application

Tags: r, for-loop, apply, lapply

I have this dataset eg. below

| Node | Descr | Node1 | Descr | Node2 | Descr |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | AAA1 | B1 | BBB1 | C1 | CCC1 |
| A2 | AAA2 | B2 | BBB2 | C2 | CCC2 |
| A3 | AAA3 |  |  | C3 | CCC3 |
| A4 | AAA4 | B4 | BBB4 | C4 | CCC4 |

and expectation is that node of the node & descr should be blank and to be replaced by previous node & descr from same row as:

| Node | Descr | Node1 | Descr | Node2 | Descr |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | AAA1 | B1 | BBB1 | C1 | CCC1 |
| A2 | AAA2 | B2 | BBB2 | C2 | CCC2 |
| A3 | AAA3 | **A3** | **AAA3** | C3 | CCC3 |
| A4 | AAA4 | B4 | BBB4 | C4 | CCC4 |

```
for (j in 8:20){
  for (i in 1:nrow(old_data)){
     if(is.na(old_data[i,j]) && !is.na(old_data[i,j+2]) && !is.na(old_data[i,j-2])){
       old_data[i,j] <- old_data[i,j-2]
       old_data[i,j+1] <- old_data[i,j-1]}
  }
}
```

Now i am able to do it using for loop as below, but as my data is huge, it takes forever to scan the data frame and fix it and was wondering if there is a faster n leaner approach to this using apply family or any other suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looping with apply isn't necessarily faster than a for-loop and in some cases, slower. But you can remove one of your for-loops and vectorize:

```
df <- data.frame(
    Node = c("A1", "A2", "A3", "A4"), 
    Descr = c("AAA1", "AAA2", "AAA3", "AAA4"), 
    Node1 = c("B1", "B2", NA, "B4"), 
    Descr1 = c("BBB1", "BBB2", NA, "BBB4"), 
    Node2 = c("C1", "C2", "C3", "C4"),
    Descr2 = c("CCC1", "CCC2", "CCC3", "CCC4"),
    Node3 = c(NA, "D2", "D3", "D4"),
    Descr3 = c(NA, "DDD2", "DDD3", "DDD4"),
    Node4 = c(NA, "E2", "E3", "E4"),
    Descr4 = c(NA, "EEE2", "EEE3", "EEE4")
)

for(i in seq(from = 3, to = ncol(df), by = 2)){
    # if the Descr column is not necessarily NA when its complementary Node 
    # column is NA, then you'll need to split this into two if-statements
    if(any(is.na(df[,i]))){
        df[,i][which(is.na(df[,i]))] <- df[,i-2][which(is.na(df[,i]))]
        df[,i+1][which(is.na(df[,i+1]))] <- df[,i-1][which(is.na(df[,i+1]))]
    }
}

df

  Node Descr Node1 Descr1 Node2 Descr2 Node3 Descr3 Node4 Descr4
1   A1  AAA1    B1   BBB1    C1   CCC1    C1   CCC1    C1   CCC1
2   A2  AAA2    B2   BBB2    C2   CCC2    D2   DDD2    E2   EEE2
3   A3  AAA3    A3   AAA3    C3   CCC3    D3   DDD3    E3   EEE3
4   A4  AAA4    B4   BBB4    C4   CCC4    D4   DDD4    E4   EEE4
```

This should be much faster if you have lots of rows.